# Не соблюдается уникальность в коллекции Set

Tags: java, spring, сессия, set

Я пишу корзину интернет-магазина. Описание проблемы: я добавляю две сессии `cart` и `cart1`, соблюдается проверка на уникальность. Но, если я удалю сессию `cart` и оставлю `cart1`, то при добавлении нового элемента уникальность не будет соблюдена. Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чем это может быть связано

```
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setMaxInactiveInterval(-1);

        Set<Product> cart = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        List<String> attribs = Arrays.asList("cart", "cart1"); // и т.д.

        for (String attr : attribs) {
            Product product = (Product) session.getAttribute(attr);
            if (null == product) {
                product = new Product(name, price, item_size, quantity, img, color);
            }
            if (cart.add(product)) { // товар успешно добавлен, нет дубликата
                session.setAttribute(attr, product);
                System.out.println("Товар " + product.getName() + " в корзине");
            }

        }

        return "redirect:/basket";
```

Класс сущности БД `Product`, в котором переопределены методы:

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Product product = (Product) o;
        return name.equals(product.name) && item_size.equals(product.item_size);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name, item_size);
    }
```

```
@PostMapping("/cart/remove")
    public String Cart_remove(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.removeAttribute("cart");
        return "redirect:/basket";
    }
```

Comment: Так "дубликат"  в сете в данном коде не появится, но получится, что в сессии атрибуты `cart` и `cart1` могут содержать одинаковые товары.  В этом проблема?  К тому же, в методах `equals/hashCode` используются значения только двух полей из шести.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если проблема заключается в том, что в некотором сценарии, когда в сессии есть атрибуты `cart` `cart1`, и после *удаления* атрибута `cart` можно добавить атрибут `cart` со значением, равным значению атрибута `cart1`, оставшемуся от прошлых операций.

Решение может заключаться в том, чтобы сначала проверить и внести в сет сушествующие атрибуты, а потом уже пытаться добавлять "новые" значения.

```java
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(-1);

Set<Product> cart = new LinkedHashSet<>();
List<String> attribs = Arrays.asList("cart", "cart1"); // и т.д.
Set<String> missingAttrs = new LinkedHashSet<>();

for (String attr : attribs) {
    Product product = (Product) session.getAttribute(attr);
    if (null == product) {
        missingAttrs.add(attr);
    } else if (cart.add(product)) { // товар успешно добавлен в сет
        System.out.println("Товар " + product.getName() + " в сессии и сете");
    }
}

for (String attr : missingAttrs) {
    Product product = new Product(name, price, item_size, quantity, img, color);
    if (cart.add(product)) { // товар успешно добавлен в сет
        System.out.println("Товар " + product.getName() + " добавлен в сессию и сет");
        session.setAttribute(attr, product);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Найден товар-дубликат " + product.getName());
    }
}

return "redirect:/basket";
```

Comment: Логика работает, как и предусматривалось! Спасибо вам!